# Java: Marshal unmarshal to .properties format?

Tags: java, properties, jaxb, marshalling

Note, this is not about marshaling a properties object.

I'd like to marshall to a properties format. Example:

```
class Foo { String a = "aaa"; Item i = new Item(); }
class Item { String val = "Value"; }

marshall( new
```

into

```
a = Hello
i.value = Value
```

I know this approach has it's limitations, but that's ok.

**Is there something along these lines?**

If not, is there some simple expression language lib which can do both - querying object *and* identifying "string keys" in it's object tree?

I've checked BeanUtils - nothing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use objectprops(http://code.google.com/p/objectprops/) for this:

```
ObjectPropertiesStore store = new ObjectPropertiesStore();

// write the object to the store        
store.writeObject(new Foo());

// let's get the Properties object and print the contents to System.out
Properties properties = store.getDatabase();
properties.store( System.out, "My test");
```

Or you could implement this in an easy way using ReflectionToStringBuilder of commons-lang and passing a custom [ToStringStyle](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringStyle.html) that you implement yourself, and the load the resulting string into a Properties object.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. It's so complete that I'm going to make it a provider for JBoss RestEasy.